# Override view-list and get items properties

Tags: 8, theming

I'm currently working on Bartik theme and i'm trying to create a custom template for the Content-Recent block available in Drupal 8
For your information, i would like to create the following block view :

[image]

For that, I've followed these steps :

- In Drupal 8 back-office, I've added the block view "Recent content" (Machine name : views_block__content_recent_block_1)
- In my source code, I've created a new file in my templates folder and named : views-view-list--content-recent--block-1.html
- I've added a static text : "Hello world", just to check if the template has been override, and it's OK for this part.

But now, I'm stuck because I don't know how to retrieve item properties (Title, Date, Description)
I've tried to find some informations with `kint()` and `dump()` but I'm bit lost :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default template for a views-view-list.html.twig. Basically you've overwritten this template when you've created views-view-list--content-recent--block-1.html.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for a view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the container.
 * - rows: A list of rows for this list.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's contents.
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - list: @todo.
 *   - type: Starting tag will be either a ul or ol.
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the list element.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_list()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{% if attributes -%}
<div{{ attributes }}>
    {% endif %}
    {% if title %}
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    {% endif %}

    <{{ list.type }}{{ list.attributes }}>

    {% for row in rows %}
        <li{{ row.attributes }}>{{ row.content }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

</{{ list.type }}>

{% if attributes -%}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

What you could do is try adding something like this inside your "for" loop:

```
{% set item = row.content['#view'].style_plugin.render_tokens[ loop.index0 ] %}
{{ item['{{ title }}'] }}
{{ item['{{ field_date }}'] }}
```

Comment: Finally by digging my variables with `kint()` and following your solution, I'm able to get the data that I want to display.

**For example** : 
To get the bundle name associated to my article : `row.content['#row`]._entity.bundle()`